# PHP find a string and get corresponding data

Tags: php, string, text

have this text

**"Number":"X0011","Name":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa","Adress":"12345","Phone":"56976585","Number":"X0044","Name":"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","Adress":"786487647","Phone":"34214234",.......**

And want to return with PHP something like this (just names and codes, and ignore all others fields)

Number:X0011

Name:aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Number:X0044

Name:bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the explode function

========

## [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$mystring  = ""Number":"X0011","Name":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa","Adress":"12345","Phone":"56976585";
$pieces = explode(",", $mystring);
echo $pieces[0]; // Number:X0011
echo $pieces[1]; // Name:aaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to cycle through all of the items and get at the individual values `$temp_str[1]` will contain the actual value of that item. It also means that you can keep adding info to the of the string and this code will parse it.

```
$str  = '"Number":"X0011","Name":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa","Adress":"12345","Phone":"56976585"';
$str = str_replace('"',"",$str); // remove the double quotes

$pieces = explode(",", $str);
foreach($pieces as $piece){
    $temp_str = explode(',',$piece);
    echo $temp_str[0]; // 'Number:'X0011 // gives the heading
    echo $temp_str[1]; // Name:'aaaaaaa' // gives the value
    echo "<br />";
}
```